# How To Implement Android Splash Screen API Without Changing The Current Theme

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-theme, android-splashscreen

I would like to add the **Android Splash Screen API** to an already developed project based on [this document](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen), which has its own styles and themes. In the document it says that the `theme` in the `application` tag of my manifest should be set to the new theme which necessarily inherits from `"Theme.SplashScreen"` and it has some required tags too inside, like this:

```
<style name="Theme.AppSplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/green</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/sample_splash</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
   
</style
```

It is while my old theme of the project inherits from some other theme and I can't change it and I can't use dual inheritance for a theme (`style` tag) too.
So my question is what can be done for such project which has already some used themes and also wants to benefit from Android's new `Splash Screen API`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement a new splash screen API without interfering with your old app theme by using the following steps

• Add default application theme to `<application> android:theme="old theme" ...</application>`

• Create launcher screen that extends `Activity`

• assign `Theme.AppSplash` (declared in question) to `android:theme` of `Activity` tag in `manifest` file

• Navigate to the next screen where you want to display

Comment: it doesn't work and the app crashes. But I just found that there is a tag which is `<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/old theme</item>` and it might solve my problem because its exactly intended for this purpose, but sadly it doesn't work too!!

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: A theme from an HMI SDK which is mandatory for our project